# NestJS E2E Testing Error: No Default Engine Specified and No Extension Was Provided

Tags: express, jestjs, nestjs, handlebars.js, supertest

I'm currently working on an end-to-end test using Jest for a NestJS application and I've encountered a problem with the test environment setup. I'm utilizing supertest for HTTP assertions, and my templates are rendered with hbs.

Here are the versions of the packages I'm using:

```
NestJS: 10
supertest: 6.3
Jest: 29.5
hbs: 4.2
```

The error occurs when I run the e2e tests with node run test:e2e. However, when I run the application normally, everything works fine.
Here's my `main.ts`:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
  app.setViewEngine('hbs');

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and here's `app.controller.ts`:

```
@Get()
@Render('index')
root() {
    return { message: 'Hello world!' };
}
```

my `app.e2e-spec.ts`:

```
describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Hello World!');
  });
});
```

Is there any additional setup I need to do for the test environment to recognize the view engine?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Like suggested by [Micael Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76712519/15982), I got this working by adding `setViewEngine()` call:

```
  // Replace INestApplication with NestExpressApplication
  let app: NestExpressApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    app.setViewEngine('hbs'); // <-- add template engine
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .expect(/Hello World!/); // <-- use regex to match part of output
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you've called `app.setViewEngine()` in the `bootstrap` function but you didn't called the bootstrap function in your test suite file. I didn't follow why you're expecting that to work

I guess you just need to add that `app.setViewEngine()` to your `app.e2e-spec.ts` as well

Comment: When I attempt to include the following lines in the app.e2e-spec.ts file:
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
app.setViewEngine('hbs');
await app.init();

I encounter the following error: Property 'setViewEngine' does not exist on type 'INestApplication<any>'.

Comment: what if you ignore the tsc error via `// @ts-ignore`? does it works? if yes, then it should be a bug/limitation on `@nestjs/testing`, so please report to https://github.com/nestjs/nest